# Grails Create Multiple Value Map

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-2.0

I have a list of Clients and each client has one or more Venues.

These are two separate Domain classes where Venue has client id

I want to create a multiple value MAP which will have Client name as Key and Venue names as value

example :

```
def dataMap=["Client1":["Venue1","Venue2","Venue3"],"Client2":["Venue1","Venue2"]]
```

Domain Class:**Client**

```
 class Client {
    String name;
    static hasMany = [venues: Venue];
}
```

Domain Class:**Venue**

```
class Venue {
    String name;
    String addressLine1;
    String addressLine2;
    String City

    static belongsTo = [client: Client];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What have you tried before and where do you stuck?

Here is one simple approach:

```
def dataMap = [:]
Client.findAllWhere(/*yourCondition*/).each { client ->
    dataMap[client.name] = client.venues.name
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The same as aiolos wrote, with the standard Groovy method `collectEntries()`:

```
def dataMap = Client.findAllWhere(/*yourCondition*/).collectEntries { client ->
    [(client.name): client.venues.name]
}
```